# How to show cheapest simple product price on product list

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-community

How to show cheapest simple product price on product list?
As far as I know the values shown on product list are values taken from `catalog_product_index_price.price` and `catalog_product_index_price.final_price`.

It seems that magento indexes prices taken from the first associated product for a configurable product.
How to override it to get the cheapest associated product instead of the first one?

Comment: Was my resonse the one you where looking for? If so please choose as chosen Anwser.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
if($_product->isConfigurable())
{
    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);
    $childPriceLowest = "";    
    $childPriceHighest = "";    

    foreach($childProducts as $child){
        $_child = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child->getId());

        if($childPriceLowest == '' || $childPriceLowest > $_child->getPrice() )
        $childPriceLowest =  $_child->getPrice();

    }
    echo $childPriceLowest;
}
```